# How does the transpose work in three or more dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For two-dimensaol array, according **Guide to numpy**

> The two-styles of memory layout for arrays are connected through the transpose operation. **Thus, if A is a (contiguous) C-style array, then the same block memory can be used to represent AT as a (contiguous) Fortran-style array.** This kindof undorctondina non ho ucoful mhon trrina to orn mmonnina of Fortron

In three dimensional matrix

```
A = np.arange(6).reshape([1,2,3])
```

we can view  A as a 1 by 1 block matrix, which means A  has one entry, and that entry is a matrix with two rows and three columns.

So we can iteratively take the transpose according to the rules above.

My question is:

```
A= np.arange(6).reshape([1,2,3])
B = A.transpose(1,2,0)
```

In this case, how does it work. Is there a rule that  can tell me how the elements of B are arranged

Comment: `np.transpose` docs explains what the `axes` parameter does.  I suspect the best thing is to just experiment and see for yourself what the different values produce.  Look at the `B.shape`.  I'd expect `(2,3,1)`.  Basically the first axis of `A` has been moved to the end.  `np.moveaxis` and `np.swapaxes` can also make changes like this.  I prefer to stick with `np.transpose`, and have used it enough to perform, with a bit of thought, any switch.

Comment: For a more indepth understanding you might need to learn about `strides`.  `transpose` switches those along with the `shape`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you very much! l learn the doucment about swapaxes and strides and i feel better!